# Different Models in Magento for same Module:

Tags: magento, collections, model

I create a Module in Magento, Now i am want to Use the Other model to take collection but thats give me error,

```
**Error:** There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1685082734
```

And my Collection class is given below..

```
class Mage_Banners_Model_Mysql4_Category_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract

{

    public function _construct()

    { 
        parent::_construct();

        $this->_init('banners/category');

    }
}
```

So how to run this and how this model resource know about has table..?

Comment: What error you get in that report?

Comment: @jamapag, the upper one **Error:**

Comment: I mean go to the `var/reposts` directory of you magento and read description of error in `1685082734` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add another model to  your custom module, you should enter your table name in `config.xml` file, which is located in yourmodule/etc folder:

```
<entities>
<banners>
    <table>Your table Name here</table>
</banners>
```

After that you should add your collection class in corresponding `model/mysql4/category/Collection.php`. You should create model class in model/file name.

Suppose `category.php` is the model file, you should initiate that model class by using these methods. These files should be in the `model` folder:

```
public function _construct()
{    
    // Note that the category_id refers to the key field in your database table.
    $this->_init('banner/category', 'category_id');
}
```